# How to insert multiple rows using a prepared statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm working on a bulk insertion class, and I have decided to use prepared statements to import my rows into the database. (Data can be entered in an invalid state, and fixed later, so it makes no sense to go through ActiveRecord).

To insert one row at a time, I can do something like this:

```
@@connection.prepare('insert_foos', <<-SQL.strip_heredoc
    INSERT INTO foos (number, registration_date, record_id)
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
    RETURNING id
  SQL
)
```

And then, to insert:

```
@@connection.exec_prepared('insert_foos', [record[:number], reg_date, record[:id])
```

But it would be preferable if I could aggregate a collection of rows to be inserted, and then insert them all using one `exec_prepared` call. Similar questions have been posed for PHP, and the suggest preparing the statement dynamically to support the number of records needed, but I would rather prepare the statement once. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple rows to the `values` clause:

```
VALUES ($1, $2, $3), ($4, $5, $6)
```

Note that `RETURNING id` will now return two rows instead of one.

Comment: This only works for two rows. I need to support an arbitrary number of rows.

Comment: You could create the `VALUES` section dynamically in Ruby